# Getting null as result of a mocked method call in Android JUnit

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to mock a function that is being called within another function. But I am getting end result as `null`. I tried to mock the second function that is being used in actual function.

Here is my code:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LoadJsonData_Test {

@Mock
LoadJsonData loadJsonData;

@Test
public void getChartTypeJS_test() {

    String jsonStr = "";
    try {
        InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("chartInfo.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        if (is.read(buffer) > 0)
            jsonStr = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        is.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    when(loadJsonData.getJsonData()).thenReturn(jsonStr);

    System.out.println(loadJsonData.getJsonData()); //Printing the data I wanted
    assertEquals(loadJsonData.getChartTypeJS(), 
"javascript:setChartSeriesType(%d);"); // loadJsonData.getChartTypeJS() returns null

}
```

Code I am trying to test:

```
public String getJsonData() {
    try {
        InputStream is = mContext.getAssets().open("chartInfo.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        if (is.read(buffer) > 0)
            jsonString = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        is.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return jsonString;
}

public String getChartTypeJS() {
    jsonString = getJsonData();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONObject javascriptEvent_JsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("javascript_events");
        return javascriptEvent_JsonObject.getString("chartType");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

What is it I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you get null? I see several methods. What do you expect instead?

Comment: because mocks return nulls

Comment: @AntonKazakov Thank you. You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mocking `LoadJsonData` and then invoking two methods on it:

- `getJsonData()`
- `getChartTypeJS()`

You create an expectation on the response from `getJsonData()` here:

```
when(loadJsonData.getJsonData()).thenReturn(jsonStr);
```

But since the mock has no expectation for a response from `getChartTypeJS()` this invocation returns null: `loadJsonData.getChartTypeJS()`.

It looks like `LoadJsonData` should be a `Spy` not a `Mock` since that would allow you to mock `getJsonData()` but invoke the actual implementation of `getChartTypeJS()`.

For example:

```
@Spy
LoadJsonData loadJsonData;

// this wil tell Mockito to return jsonStr when getJsonData() is invoked on the spy
doReturn(jsonStr).when(loadJsonData.getJsonData());

// this will invoke the actual implementation
assertEquals(loadJsonData.getChartTypeJS(), "javascript:setChartSeriesType(%d);");
```

More details on spying (aka partial mocks) [here](http://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy).

Comment: That makes sense to me now. Thank you. But since JSONObject is part of android.jar we cannot use JSONObject calls. So should I use Roboelectric or what do u suggest @glytching

Comment: I'm not sure what that last comment refers to. Is it perhaps a [follow up question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)?

Comment: I am getting this as a error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getJSONObject in org.json.JSONObject not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details. @glytching

Comment: I think that's a [follow up question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions).

Comment: Refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48283057/how-to-use-jsonobjects-in-writing-local-tests-using-junit-mockito   @glytching